# How to remove special character in file using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file and I want to remove special character "[","]" at the beginning and end from each row.

```
[65,898,"screwball comedy"]
[121,778,"dark comedy"]
[121,1288,"comedy"]
[121,2706,"teen comedy"]
[121,35836,"comedy"]
[121,35836,"sex comedy"]
[121,36529,"dark comedy"]
```

How to remove" [" and" ]" from all file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `trim` function :

```
val df = spark.read.text(path)
val df1 = df.withColumn("value", expr("trim(both '][' from value)"))

df1.show(false)
//+-------------------------+
//|value                    |
//+-------------------------+
//|65,898,"screwball comedy"|
//|121,778,"dark comedy"    |
//|121,1288,"comedy"        |
//|121,2706,"teen comedy"   |
//|121,35836,"comedy"       |
//|121,35836,"sex comedy"   |
//|121,36529,"dark comedy"  |
//+-------------------------+
```

Or using `regexp_replace`:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("value", regexp_replace(col("value"), "[\\[\\]]", ""))
```

Comment: I used regexp_replace to remove special character but it separate the word itself not special character.
@blackbishop